# "Request was made" or "request has made" or "request has been made"

Tags: grammaticality

Which of the following sentence is correct/apt to notate the past action which was not executed till date?

Sentence 1:

> A request was made for grant of permission to X  on April 2013 but it was not done yet.

Sentence 2:

> A request has made for grant of permission to X on April 2013 but it was not done yet.

Sentence 3:

> A request has been made for granting of permission to X on April 2013 but it was not done yet.

Comment: Your statements are a little ambiguous.  Was the request made in April 2013, or was the request for permission to be allowed to X during April 2013?  And was the permission not granted yet, or was the permission granted but no one actually did any X'ing during the month of April 2013?

Comment: I suppose what you mean is:  "A request was made in April, 2013 for permission to X. It is now September and we have received no response. Could you please tell me the status of this request."  Which is not the most polite way to phrase it, but it conveys a little hint that you are annoyed that it's been over 4 months with no response.

Answer (score 1):

There are several points here.

When a sentence refers to an event at a particular time in the past, the past tense, rather than the present perfect construction, is used, at least in British English, as in the first part of sentence 1.

The present perfect construction, again in British English, is used to describe a past event that has current relevance, or which refers to the time up until now. That requires the second part of the sentence to read *. . . but it has not been done yet*.

*A request . . . for grant of permission to* is a little unusual, but it may perhaps be used formulaically in certain legal contexts. Elsewhere, it might be more usual to find *a request . . . to grant permission to*.

In the second half of the sentence, it might be preferable to repeat *made*, rather than use *done*.

When a month, rather than a specific date is referred to, the preposition used is *in* rather than *on*.

The adverb *yet* is perhaps better placed after *has not*, rather than at the end of the sentence.

Putting all this together, the sentence would be more likely to occur in British English as:

> A request was made to grant permission to X in April 2013, but it has
>   not yet been made .

I’ve specified British English, because I know that American English makes different choices between the past tense and the present perfect construction, and a speaker of American English might give a different answer.

Comment: If I'm understanding the sentence correctly, I would remove 'grant' from the first part and substitute it into the later bit, and generally reduce the number of redundant nouns and verbs: “Permission to _X_ was requested in April 2013 but has not been granted yet”. This is assuming, of course, that the intended meaning is not that someone requested to be allowed to grant someone else permission to do _X_.

Comment: Like the explanation, but I find your example very confusing. *What* has not yet been made?  *..it has not yet been complied with* perhaps.

Comment: Agreed. I find it confusing too on re-reading it. Perhaps it should have been ' . . . but the permission has not yet been granted.'

Answer (score 0):

This question is horribly confusing to a native speaker. *A grant of permission* does exist in certain contexts, mostly legalese, where it is not exactly the same as *the granting of permission*, or just *permission* which is normal. *Permission to X*  only works where X is a verb; if a noun, the phrase is *permission for X*.  'A request was made'  is (unless done for effect) less natural and forceful than 'I made a request'. The request may have been made 'in April 2013' or 'on April 3rd', but not 'on April'.  And 'not executed till date' may mean it has not been done yet, or that it was only done today.

All these points will affect the choice of words; until you clarify the question, any answer is just a guess.